# How to have index of min value in associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like:

```
Array([0]=>array('field1'=>aNumber,'field2'=>'something'),
[1]=>array('field1'=>aNumber,'field2'=>'something'),
[2]=>array('field1'=>aNumber,'field2'=>'something'),
[3]=>array('field1'=>aNumber,'field2'=>'something'));
```

I have to get the index of array that has min the field `aNumber`..

For example:

```
Array([0]=>array('field1'=>10,'field2'=>'something'),
[1]=>array('field1'=>3,'field2'=>'something'),
[2]=>array('field1'=>100,'field2'=>'something'),
[3]=>array('field1'=>9,'field2'=>'something'));
```

the index i want is `1`.

I know is possible using a loop and some if storing the iterate index.. but i want to know if there is some php function that shortens the algorithm
how can i do? thanks!!!

Comment: array_walk, array_filter... but no, you can't avoid a loop, because the php array search-related functions can't handle arbitrary multi-dimensional arrays. if you want an arbitrary-structure array searched, you'll have to provide the search function yourself.

Comment: Note that it's more likely that writing your own function for this would be more efficient, than using a composition of functions which employ their own loops anyway.

Comment: I doubt doing anything else that a simple `foreach` will make it faster or make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no built-in function like this.
But you can use other functions with callbacks ..
[array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk), [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

(And a built-in function will probably do same as you will do with a loop and iterate through the items of your array)